# Dynamic Javascript Included with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic-programming, server-side-includes

I'm building an application (literally, an online application) and I'd like to dynamically call Js files/functions into play only when they are needed.  Additionally, and this is the kicker, it would actually benefit me to be able to pass php variables and functions with return values into the Js code.  This way, the variables passed will occur server-side, and I'll have the benefit of only having the client-side code I need at the time.

To this end I'm considering creating multiple PHP files that simple contain the following:

```
<?
//JS CODE FOR PAGE 1 (ETC.)
//HEADER FUNCTIONS
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

//FUNCTIONS, METHODS, ETC WITH THE ABILITY TO INSERT PHP VARIABLES LIKE SO:
var name = <?= $name ?>

</script>
```

Does anyone have any objections?  Why would this NOT be an efficient way to manage Js code, call it dynamically by including, and passing data?  What am I not thinking of?

Comment: If `name` is a string, you should do this: `var name = '<?= $name ?>'`

Comment: Good call, i'll definitely do that if I end up going this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my applications I am also loading only js-files, if needed. I don't know if you do, but I am using a MVC-structure. So while predispatching I am checking if there is an js-file existing with the same name as my controller for example. This way they get only loaded, if the controller/action really needs it. But this way I am only including static js-files, nothing dynamic with PHP-variables. I guess, I just didn't need that so far ;)

But making your js-files related to a controller or action within the controller or both is a very great way to load only the js-files, which I really need.

Comment: faileN - That's a GREAT idea! and, yes, I am using an MVC structure.  I'll probably start using organizing that way regardless of the outcome of this question, but what do you think about passing data into the Js files once they're included?  Other suggested XML or Json objects, but why not package them the way I suggested?

Using your idea, i could even create a sort of 'library' that would be loaded in the controller.  thoughts?

Comment: I guess I'm more trying to see what the drawbacks would be to my approach

Comment: I think your idea, filling data into the already included js-files is also a cool idea, if it fits your needs. As I mentioned, I did not need such things until now. I just thought about a drawback of doing things like `var foo = <?= $bar ?>;`. I don't know if that's an issue, but as far as I know Javascript will be cached. That means if you call for example `myjsscript.php` (= PHP-file with sending js-Headers, so browser thinks this is a js-file) several times and only change the php-var you are using in your js, the browser may don't get it, and results in a wrong output. However putting...

Comment: ...data into the js via json or xml, would work I guess. Let me know, which approach you used, when developing your application ;)

Comment: Turns out the caching issue is actually not really much of an issue at all (whew) but this was EXACTLY what I was looking for, as far as anything that could make this a 'bad' idea.  thanks faileN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) function of PHP to make your PHP objects usable in JavaScript like `<script type="text/javascript">
var name = <?= json_encode($name) ?>;
</script>`

Comment: Also Xml-data would be possible, not only json.

Comment: So, are you suggesting I create a, sort of, global variable that can be passed into normally referenced Js files?

Doing this seems like it would require me to link my Js files as I am now, then pass this object in and parse it to obtain the correct values.  Is this what you meant? Seems feasible, but why would you recommend your approach vice mine?  Which becomes more efficient?